# Make Sure Mysql is up before starting Tomcat Server

Tags: mysql, tomcat9

**Machine 1:** MySQL Installed

**Machine 2:** Tomcat Installed to run PIR war

During monthly maintenance, IT team restarted the server. Consider Machine 2 restarted first before Machine 1, and Machine 2 was up before Machine 1. During Tomcat startup, it got failed because of MySQL unavailable in Machine 1.

In order to successful start it needs MySQL need to be started in first place or Tomcat should wait for MySQL.